# Exposing Apex REST Services using OpenAPI

Tags: apexrest

I'm trying to find the recommended approach for exposing custom Apex REST services using OpenAPI(fka Swagger). I found most articles on Salesforce consuming OpenAPI spec in external services but couldn't find a much info on how custom Apex REST services could be exposed as a Swagger Doc.

Comment: @identigral - Thanks for sharing the question. I understand that Salesforce doesn't offer it currently, but I was looking for workaround options. Thanks!

Comment: There's no automated, tool-based workaround. You can compose an OpenAPI spec yourself manually.

Comment: @identigral - Thank you for the input!